# OpenCV reduce() Array to vector average

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

Using OpenCV 3.4.1 in C++ I have a 2 dimensional Mat array object. These first few lines just explain essentially how the data are obtained to fill this Mat object ("dat")

```
int rows=NUMBER_OF_ROWS;
int cols=NUMBER_OF_COLS;
float* rawdata;
rawdata = new float[rows*cols];
fits_read_img(FP, TFLOAT, firstpixel, npixels, &nullval, rawdata, &anynull, &status);
```

Then creation of the Mat object from the raw data looks like this:

```
cv::Mat dat = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_32FC1, rawdata);
```

So far, so good, and I've used this Mat object "dat" for many things. But now I want to create a row average of the data. That should give me a rows x 1 vector, with every column of each row reduced into a single value, the average of all the values in that row. Something like this:

[image]

So OpenCV has a reduce() function. Here is how I've tried calling it:

```
std::vector<float> vec(rows);
cv::reduce(dat, vec, 1, cv::REDUCE_AVG, CV_32FC1);
```

which segfaults. If I go the other direction, I.E.

```
cv::reduce(dat, vec, 0, cv::REDUCE_AVG, CV_32FC1);
```

then I get a 1 x cols vector containing a column average. In fact, it gives me the exact equivalent of this:

```
int r, c;
float sum;
for (c=0; c<cols; c++) {
  sum=0;
  for (r=0; r<rows; r++) {
    sum += dat.at<float>(r,c);
  }
  std::cout << "sum=" << ss << " avg=" << ss/r << std::endl;
}
```

So I could certainly use a brute-force method like this to get the row average that I want, but it seems I ought to be able to get it with a single cv::reduce() call.

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you use a `cv::Mat` instead of that `std::vector`?

Comment: That did it, thanks! Submit that as an answer instead of a comment so I can flag this as answered.

Comment: Sure, in a bit, somewhat busy right now. I understand why it won't work with a simple `vector` -- that is treated as a single row `Mat` once it goes through `InputArray` wrapper, but here we need a single column. I still wanna grok how to deal with 2D (or column) vectors.